# Python regex to find either one or the other

Tags: python

I have the following regex that checks for the word "Read" but i'm looking for it to check for either "Read" or "Deleted"

```
len(re.findall("Read", phrase))
```

How can I make the regex so it's looking for either Read or Deleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match exact "multiple" strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953272/how-to-match-exact-multiple-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternatives (separated by a pipe `|`) to search for either "Read" or "Deleted":

```
len(re.findall("Read|Deleted", phrase))
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use that... I feel like that is more intended for escaping an unknown/external string, rather than a string literal that can be escaped directly in the source code (and rather efficiently with r-strings).

Comment: What is the benefit of a non-capturing group over a plain `r"Read|Deleted"` here?

Comment: None, wasn't sure you could use them outside capture groups. Will edit.

Answer (score -1):

the pattern match must be independent of search word order

```
 phrase = " hello world Deleted,Undeleted,Read in a sentence"
 results=re.search("(Read|Deleted|Undeleted).*(Read|Deleted|Undeleted).* (Read|Deleted|Undeleted).*", phrase).groups()
 for group in results:
     print(group)
```

output

```
Deleted
Undeleted
Read
```