# Need to ignore lines and replace words in a csv python

Tags: python, csv

i have to ignore some lines and replace some words in a csv, i tried using the following to replace but it looks like it gets ignored

```
if "myword" not in line:
```

to replace text i used

```
csv_writer.writerow(line.replace("oldword", "newword"))
```

but this gets an error
does someone knows why?
EDIT WITH CODE

```
import csv

with open(r'excelfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('new_names.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['value', 'type', 'description']
        writer=csv.writer(new_file)

        csv_writer =csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter= ',', extrasaction='ignore')

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Please show the full contents of line, and create a minimum reproducible example that we can just cut and paste to run on out own machines. Without seeing at least a minimal example of your data, I don't think we can answer this question.

Comment: i edited the post with the code

Comment: This is the code without the 2 lines that i need to add in order to let it work

Comment: OK, that's helpful, now can you show where you want to put the broken lines, the actual contents of `line` when they don't work, and what you would like them to do? I'd like to be able to reproduce the incorrect behaviour you're having trouble with.

Comment: i want to delete the lines with the word i don't need and replace the words during the copy of the csv to a new one, so i wanted to put the 2 lines of code after "for line in csv_reader:"

Comment: So, because you're using a `csv.DictReader`, the values are nested in a dictionary structure. For example, if the file has a line that reads `has myword,and oldword,foo`, the `line` variable will contain `OrderedDict([('value', 'has myword'), ('type', 'and oldword'), ('description', 'foo')])`. So your tests have to be taking that into account.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what can be the problem.

Comment: Thanks i will try the fix as soon as possible and try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using a csv.DictReader, the values are nested in a dictionary structure. For example, if the file has a line that reads:

```
has myword,and oldword,foo
```

the line variable will contain:

```
OrderedDict([('value', 'has myword'), ('type', 'and oldword'), ('description', 'foo')])
```

Just like @furas suggested in the comments, I determined this by adding `print(line)` in the `for line...` loop.

So your logical tests have to be taking that into account.

Here are a few examples that you can adapt to fit your exact purpose:

```
import csv

with open(r'excelfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('new_names.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['value', 'type', 'description']
        writer=csv.writer(new_file)

        csv_writer =csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter= ',', extrasaction='ignore')

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            # Substitute oldword by newword in all values in line
            line = {k: v.replace("oldword", "newword") for k, v in line.items()}

            # Reject line if any value in line is exactly "myword":
            if "myword" not in line.values():
                csv_writer.writerow(line)

            # Reject line if any value in line contains "myword" as a substring:
            if not any("myword" in value for value in line.values()):
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: OK this worked thanks, but what if i wanted more words to be rejected?

Comment: Matching multiple strings has been asked before. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4953272/3216427 might help, or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/54481198/3216427